# Android studio strange warning

Tags: java, android-studio, settext

I'm new to code in Android Studio and when i set a integer in a text like this:

```
textview.setText(String.format("%d",1));
```

This code give me back a warning:

> Implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs: Use String.format (Locale,...)

What is the correct code for put an integer in a .setText?

I founded more question on stackoverflow but don't apply to this.

Comment: `textview.setText(String.valueOf(intValue));` or `textview.setText("1");`

Comment: agree with @sameerasy

Comment: you can try 

`textView.setText(int_var+"");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the correct code for put an integer in a .setText?

You simply need to convert your `int` as a `String`, you can use [`Integer.toString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-) for this purpose.

*Your code should then be:*

```
textview.setText(Integer.toString(myInt));
```

If you want to set a **fixed value** simply use the corresponding **`String` literal**.

*So here your code could simply be:*

```
textview.setText("1");
```

---

You get this warning because `String.format(String format, Object... args)` will use **the default locale** for your instance of the `Java Virtual Machine` which could cause behavior change according to the chosen format since you could end up with a format locale dependent.

For example if you simply add a comma in your format to include the grouping characters, the result is now locale dependent as you can see in this example:

```
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.FRANCE, "10000 for FR is %,d", 10_000));
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "10000 for US is %,d", 10_000));
```

**Output:**

```
10000 for FR is 10 000
10000 for US is 10,000
```

Comment: so in what case "%d" is useful?

Comment: so i can use %d only if i specify the locale language?

Comment: it is only useful for more complex String format not to print only a primitive type

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, depends on your primitive type, if you wan't to print some decimal number with a limit decimal length, this is easiest, at least I think ;)

Comment: it depends on your context if you want the result to be localized or fixed. A warning is only meant to warn you just in case you are not aware of it, if you know what you are doing you can just ignore it

Comment: @AxelH well providing a format is already context specific, you could even provide a format with integers too, but I agree that it is important to mention it to avoid misunderstandings